# Access 2010 sum rows based on two other rows

Tags: ms-access-2010

There are a few similar queries to mine but I can't quite figure it out. In Access 2010 I have one table with three columns, day, week and number.

```
   Day     Week    Number
 Monday      1       12
 Monday      2       24
 Tuesday     2       10
 Thursday    1       12
 Monday      1       10
 Tuesday     2       10
```

I want to be able to count (sum) the total "number" for Monday in Week 1, Monday in Week 2 etc.

```
   Day     Week    Total
 Monday     1       22
 Monday     2       24
 Tuesday    2       20
Thursday    1       12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a TOTALS Query.

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.dayFieldColumn, 
    yourTable.weekFieldColumn, 
    Sum(yourTable.numberColumnName) As TotalSum
FROM 
    yourTable
GROUP BY 
    yourTable.dayFieldColumn, 
    yourTable.weekFieldColumn;
```